# Rietveld and upload.py oauth2 flow seems broken

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth

I am having some serious trouble using Rietveld's upload.py script with the oauth2 flow. It will generate the diffs, prompt for the access token ( when using `--no_oauth2_webbrowser` ) and then fail when POSTing to /upload. It is properly sending the `Authorization: Oauth XXXXXXXX` header, but the Rietveld instance returns `302` every time, which code comments indicate is actually Google's way of letting you know authentication has failed. `upload.py` throws this stack trace after retrying three times:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../rietveld/upload.py", line 2719, in <module>
    main()
  File "../rietveld/upload.py", line 2711, in main
    RealMain(sys.argv)
  File "../rietveld/upload.py", line 2667, in RealMain
    response_body = rpc_server.Send("/upload", body, content_type=ctype)
  File "../rietveld/upload.py", line 464, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req, timeout=70)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 437, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 475, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: Found
```

Rietveld is running as a GAE project, using a custom domain through a Google Apps account with working SSL. I have generated Oauth2 credentials for the GAE project and installed them as specified on the [Rietveld wiki](https://github.com/rietveld-codereview/rietveld/wiki/Deploying-Rietveld). The Rietveld instance will correctly generate an access token when I visit `/get-access-token`. I am not behind a proxy. Login is restricted to members of my Google Apps domain. I have added the `login: required` config line to `app.yaml` under the `/*` route. I can successfully log in to the Rietveld instance via the web portal. I can also successfully upload a patch set using `upload.py` and the soon-to-be-deprecated ClientAuth (password) flow. I've tried it with python 2.7.6 and 2.7.10. There is an SSL/SNI issue with 2.7.6 when using the custom domain, but that is a red herring.

As an experiment, I also have attempted this with a project from a personal Google account hosted at the default appspot.com address. I have run into the same problem there.

My research has gotten me nowhere; I'm posting here before I get too far into the Rietveld source. Does anyone have anything else I should check? I am new to GAE. If no-one else is seeing this, it is probably configuration, but I am at my wits' end trying to figure out where/what it might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is not an ideal situation, but my solution is to add explicit url's within `app.yaml` for the upload-related routes and exempt them from `login: required`. I then hack the corresponding view functions in Rietveld core and decorated them with `@login_required`. Initially I had assumed that the YAML setting was just a convenience for this. However, sprinkling some logging in to try and figure out how the redirect was actually being generated indicated that this was not the case. I do not know why the `app.yaml` `login: required` directive doesn't seem to care about OAuth tokens; maybe someone can help me understand or point me in the direction of a better solution.